# Documentation or specification for .step and .stp files

Tags: step, stp

I am looking for some kind of specification, documentation, explanation, etc. for .stp/.step files.
It's more about what information each line contains instead of a general information.

I can't seem to figure out what each value means all by myself.
Does anyone know some good readings about STEP files?

I already searched google but all I got were information about the general structure instead of each particular value.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The structure of STEP-File, i.e. the grammar and the logic behind how the file is organized is described in the [standard ISO 10303-21](http://www.iso.org/iso/home/store/catalogue_tc/catalogue_detail.htm?csnumber=33713).

ISO 10303 or STEP is divided into [Application Protocols (AP)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_10303#Coverage_of_STEP_Application_Protocols_.28AP.29). Each AP defines a schema written in EXPRESS. The schemas are available on the Internet: the [CAX-IF](https://www.cax-if.org/joint_testing_info.html#schemas) provides some, [STEPtools](http://www.steptools.com/support/stdev_docs/express/) has some good HTML documentations.

The reference of the AP schemas is hosted on [stepmod](http://stepmod.cvs.sourceforge.net/viewvc/stepmod/stepmod/data/modules/).

Comment: Thank you for providing those links. That's what I needed.

Comment: The STEPtools link greets me with basicauth :'(